# Would an emp-grenade disable cyber-/bodyware?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun-sr5, equipment

I recently got my hands on some shadowrun4 books, and one of them has the emp-grenade in it. The emp-grenade says (translated out of my head, as I only own the german version) that it disables most **electronic devices** in its explosion radius, and describes the rules for the roll. But it doesn't really define what it means with "**electronic device**" and what is excluded. Does Cyberware fall into that category? Is cyberware even defined as a "device" in that sense? The grenade should be able to disable most cars (as they are electric cars), right? If so, then cyberware should be too, right?

please note that my question specifically refers to *shadowrun5*, the sr4 tag is just there because I plan to maybe use the sr4 emp-grenade in my sr5 game.

Comment: Logically, any cyberware that does not have defences against EMP is going to be a pretty poor quality. But I am not familiar with any such rules as such.

Comment: Are you concerned about the game balance issues introducing such an item may create, or have you already worked those out? (For example, such an items seems as if it would give magicians an even greater advantage than they already enjoy.)

Comment: Yes, I am concerned about just that, that's why I asked ;)

Comment: I suggest, then, that you ask that question directly, perhaps as a separate question aimed at *Shadowrun, 4th Edition* folks who are familiar with the EMP grenade's (*ahem*) impact on campaigns. Seriously, I don't know much about *Shadowrun* (*first* edition gathers dust my shelf, I guess), but I know *antimagic field* sucks for *everyone*, and an EMP is pretty close to a technology *antimagic field.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full description of the EMP Grenade is in the SR4 book Arsenal, on pg. 57:

> This weapon does not detonate like a normal
>   grenade, instead sending out a powerful electromagnetic pulse
>   designed to create damaging current and voltage surges in electronic
>   items. Though most electronics in 2070 are optical based,
>   an EMP blast can still affect power supplies, anything linked to an
>   antenna or electric cable, or older/cheaper devices with integrated
>   circuits, transistors, inductors, or silicon chips. Most cyberware is
>   also unaffected; RFID chips, however, are extremely vulnerable
>   to EMP attacks.

In the description itself, it states that it does not affect most cyberware.

From an SR5 perspective, it is a bit vague. At multiple points, SR states that the world's electronics are primarily fiber-optic, which would make them much less vulnerable (if not immune) to EMP. As SR5 is also set in 2075, whereas Arsenal came out in the 2070 era of SR4, we can also assume that cybertechnology has at least maintained the status quo, if not advanced. Cyberware is not flat-out stated to be immune to EMP, but we can infer that it would not be adversely affected by it.

The rules for the EMP grenade could be slotted into SR5 without much trouble, the only thing that would cause trouble would be the loss of Signal to commlinks, which could be implemented as Noise instead.

TLDR: Cyberware in SR4 not affected, Cyberware in SR5 most likely not affected. EMP grenade usable with Signal -> Noise change